# Circular window drop shadow effect WPF

Tags: c#

I have the following window code which has a circular border within a transparent square window giving the effect of a circular window. How do I get a Circular drop shadow that is effectively an offset of the circle towards the bottom right. I have tried all sorts of drop shadow effects but unable to get a circular appearance drop shadow.

Many thanks

```
<Window x:Class="UserTraining.ConfirmRestartWindow"    
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"       
Title="Window1" Width="280"
AllowsTransparency="True"        
ResizeMode="NoResize" ShowInTaskbar="False" Topmost="True" 
WindowStyle="None" Height="280" Background="Transparent"
 ShowActivated="False" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" >

<Grid >
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="140,140,140,140" >           
        <Border.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Saturn.png"></ImageBrush>
        </Border.Background>           
    </Border>               
</Grid>
```

Comment: Generally speaking, you cannot draw outside the `<Window>` - you'll need to create an additional Win32 Window, physically larger than your window, which is placed below your application's window - this is how frameworks like MahApps do their drop-shadow effects: https://mahapps.com/controls/metro-window.html (MahApps doesn't use an actual `<Window>` element for the drop-shadow window, but it still creates new Win32 hWnds. Use Spy++ to see how they do it).

Comment: Perfect thank you.